# fatal: I don't handle protocol '' while pushing to upstream

Tags: git

```
$ git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master


$  git push --set-upstream origin master
fatal: I don't handle protocol ''

$ git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

$  git push --set-upstream origin master
fatal: I don't handle protocol ''

$ git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Comment: It looks like your remote URL is misconfigured.  What does `git remote -v` show?

Comment: Pierre@PIERRE-PC ~/Projects/datasciencecoursera (master)
$ git remote -v
datasciencecoursera     ://github.com/pbxavier/datasciencecoursera.git (fetch)
datasciencecoursera     ://github.com/pbxavier/datasciencecoursera.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/pbxavier/datasciencecoursera (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/pbxavier/datasciencecoursera (push)

Comment: When folks ask for additional information it's best to update the question rather than leaving comments, because comments don't really have many options for proper formatting.  But yeah, you seem to be missing the protocol on those URLs there (they start with `://` instead of `https://`).  @VonC's answer should sort you out.

Comment: I begun again all the process on another computer. I reinstalled Git and created a local remote and a remote repo on Github with a new username and mail as credentials. This the steps .

Comment: I begun again all the process :  
Guest@Tsubasa MINGW64 ~
$ mkdir ~/datasciencecoursera

Guest@Tsubasa MINGW64 ~
$ cd ~/datasciencecoursera

Guest@Tsubasa MINGW64 ~/datasciencecoursera
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/Guest/datasciencecoursera/.git/

Guest@Tsubasa MINGW64 ~/datasciencecoursera (master)
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/pbx2/datasciencecoursera.git

Comment: $ git push --set-upstream origin master
Fatal: Exception encountered.
Username for 'https://github.com': pbx2
Fatal: Exception encountered.
To https://github.com/pbx2/datasciencecoursera.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/pbx2/datasciencecoursera.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
...

Answer (score 17):

Try and reset the push url to:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>
```

Replace `<username>` with your GitHub user account, and `<reponame>` with your datasciencecoursera repo name.

Comment: Thankyou! I was trying tu push to gitlab via oauth2, sometimes copying from webpage you have spaces in the string.  So first check the current setting with 'git remote -v' then even if it looks good try command above.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and I did the following, run the following command

```
1. git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>
```

replace username and reponame then run

```
2. git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Its a Secure protocol error of the Https. (in ssl happends too)
its fixed with the info that VonC said.
git remote set-url origin https://github.com//

just follow Vonc instructions.